# k8s high availability configuration edge cases for prod

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes

we have an app in production which need to be highly available (100%),so we did the following:

1. We configure 3 instance as HA but then the node died
2. We configure anti-affinity (to run on differents nodes) but some update done on the nodes and we were unavailable(evicted) for some min.
3. Now we consider to add pod disruption Budget
   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/

My question are:

1. How the affinity works with pod disruption Budget, could be any collusion ? or this is redundant configs ?
2. is there any other configuration which I need to add to make sure that my pods **run always** (as much as possible )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How the affinity works with pod disruption Budget, could be any collusion ? or this is redundant configs ?

[Affinity and Anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) is about **where** your Pod is scheduled, e.g. so that two replicas of the same app is not scheduled to the same node. [Pod Disruption Budgets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#pod-disruption-budgets) is about to increase availability when using *voluntary disruption* e.g. maintenance. They are both related to making better availability for your app - but not related to eachother.

> Is there any other configuration which I need to add to make sure that my pods run always (as much as possible)

Things will fail. What you need to do is to embrace **distributed systems** and make all your workload a distributed system, e.g. with multiple instances to remove *single point of failure*. This is done differently for *stateless* (e.g. [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)) and *stateful* (e.g. [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)) workload. What's important for you is that your **app** is available at much as possible, but individual instances (e.g. Pods) can fail, almost without that any user notice it.

> We configure 3 instance as HA but then the node died

Things will always fail. E.g. a physical node may crash. You need to design your apps so that it can tolerate some failures.

If you use a cloud provider, you should use *regional clusters* that uses three independent *Availability Zones* and you need to spread your workload so that it runs in more than one *Availability Zone* - in this way, your app can tolerate that a whole *Availability Zone* is *down* without affecting your users.